# Sine wave signal lagging; potentiometer has inductance?

Tags: resistors, inductance, sine

my sine wave at the midpoint of potentiometer is lagging by 74 degree when comparing to the input, and my potentiometer is 500Kohm. Is there a low inductance potentiometer?
I do not know how to pick a resistor, potentiometer with low inductance. What do I look for in Digikey and mouser to have a resistor with low inductance.

Comment: More likely it is due to load capacitance. Please tell us the frequency and show us the circuit the pot is connected to. How are you measuring the 'lagging'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it is simply a potentiometer, and I am measuring the input sine wave and comparing that to the sinewave from the midpoint of potentiometer. The frequency is 200kHz.

Comment: It would help if you told us what potentiometer you have.

Comment: At 200kHz it doesn't take too much stray capacitance to be observable. How are you measuring it? The measuring device will have input capacitance.

Comment: I explained how RC affects phase lag due your scope probe and you never asked what you  did not understand nor why phase matters. Why is that? I see I made abrainfart on R

Comment: Do you realize even an op amp will have phase shift due to GBW product if only 1MHz GBW and some gain?

Answer (score 5):

When driven by a low impedance source, at its midpoint the [Thevenin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) equivalent resistance of a 500 kΩ pot is 125 kΩ (250k || 250k). In combination with the parasitic capacitance in the pot and wires and the input capacitance of your scope probe, this will form an RC low pass filter. The formula for phase angle of an RC flow pass filter is φ = −arctan(ωCR). At 74° and 200 kHz this corresponds to ~22 pF.

Pot capacitance will be distributed between the wiper and ends with a ratio that depends on the dimensions of the wiper and case etc. The values may only be a few pF, and in the center position it will probably be close to the same in both directions, therefore having little effect because the capacitor division ratio is similar to the resistor ratio.

Active scope probes can be less than 5 pF, but passive 10x probes are are typically around 10~20 pF. This suggests that the primary cause of your phase shift is the measuring equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's a wirewound pot it won't have much inductance. And a 500K pot is not wirewound.

However the output Z will be 0 to 125K ohm and a loading of only a few pF will affect it profoundly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFtKSY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is what the output Vout looks like compared to the ideal output with the pot set to mid-scale (maximum source impedance).

[image]

It's difficult to get the stray and input capacitances extremely low, so most precision AC circuits such as AC measurement bridges will use low kHz frequencies and low K-ohm impedances.

Comment: Interesting that you brought up wheatstone bridge. I am doing something similar, and the ac signals from the midpoint of two branch are not in-phase. Your recommendation is to use low frequency and low resistance. hmm...